# SQL: Query UNION Error while joining 2 tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, group-by, union

I have 2 datasets, Products and OrderDetails (Northwind dataset)

**Products dataset**

```
ProductID   ProductName SupplierID  CategoryID  QuantityPerUnit     UnitPrice   UnitsInStock 
1               Chai        1              1     10 boxes x 20 bags   18.00             39         
2                Chang      1              1     24 - 12 oz bottles   19.00             17        
3              Aniseed      1              2     12 - 550 ml          10.00             13         
4            Seasoning      2              2     48 - 6 oz jars       22.00             53  
5             Gumbo Mix     2              2     36 boxes             21.35              0
```

**Order Details dataset**

```
ProductID   UnitPrice   OrderID Quantity    Discount
1             18.00     10248   10            0
42              9.80    10248   10            0
72             34.80    10248   5             0
1              18.00    10249   10            0
51             42.40    10249   40            0   and so on
1              18.00    10270   12            0
```

**Query**

```
SELECT ProductName, Count([Order Details].OrderID)
FROM ([Order Details] UNION Products ON [Order Details].OrderID = Products.OrderID)
WHERE [Order Details].Quantity = 10
GROUP BY ProductName
```

**Expected Output**

```
Product Name (from Products dataset)    How many OrderIDs had this product where quantity = 10
Chai                                     2
```

Here since 2 order IDs had Chai, 10248 and 10249, where quantity = 10, we only considered these cases.
 But I am getting error in query'
'

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
```

Comment: I think you confused `union` with `join`

Comment: `UNION` is not another `JOIN`. You use it between queries: `SELECT x FROM y UNION SELECT z FROM p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a `JOIN` rather than `UNION`. However, for this dataset, I would go for a correlated subquery:

```
select
    p.*,
    (
        select count(*) 
        from orderDetails od 
        where od.productID = p.productID and od.quantity = 10
    ) no_orders
from products p
```

The upside of this approach are that:

- it avoids outer aggregation
- you get a results also for products that do not have a matching orders (they would get a count of `0`)
- the subquery is executed only once per product anyway, so there is no penalty compared to the `join` approach; I would expect that this would perform equally well, or better, assuming an index on `orderDetails(productID, quantity)`

Comment: . . You might want to upvote questions that you answer that have negative votes.  They have a disconcerting habit of being deleted at future points in time.  This is particularly irritating when the question seems quite clear to you and is closed as being unclear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I usually do, but I might have forgotten this one. Fixed. Overall I find that questions are being downvoted quite to often on SO... I find that the lack of upvote is a good indication of the quality of a question already!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
select
    productName,
    count(*) as total_orders
from products p
join order o
on p.productId = o.productId
where Quantity = 10
group by
    productName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select p.ProductName , count(o.ProductID) from dbo.Products p
join dbo.Orders o
on p.ProductID = o.ProductID where o.Quantity = '10'
group by o.ProductID, p.ProductName
```

Hope this helps.